# Overriding the default test output file name in soapui

Tags: soapui

I am using SoapUI-5.2.1. I have created a new test suite and i am running this test suite from commandline using testrunner.bat. I am also saving the output results in junit format by using testsuite->Launch testrunner->Reports tab. I have given the root folder. I also want to override the output file name like 'Application name_Soapui_results'.  But currently i don't see the option to override the output file name. By default output filename is coming as 'Test-TestSuite Name'.Is there any way i can override the default output file name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no way to override the output name. For a complete list of options that you can override, see [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-command-line/functional-tests.html).

If you are running your test from command line, you should be able to wrap that and renaming of the output into a single script.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please explain me how to wrap and renaming of the output into a single script.

Comment: @dhasank That is WAY outside of the scope of this question, and not appropriate for this medium. You will need to search for some tutorials on writing [tag:batch-file] scripts.